# Different before_deploy for each provider on TravisCI

Tags: heroku, travis-ci

I currently have a Github repo with two folders, backend and frontend. In each folders there's an app I need to deploy to a given provider. I'm using TravisCI to auto-deploy.

I'd like to be able to do different before_deploy steps for each provider. Is there a way to do that with TravisCI?

Here's what my .travis.yml looks like so far:

```
language: java
jdk:
    - oraclejdk8
before_install:
    - cd backend
before_deploy: 
    - cd backend
deploy:
    - provider: cloudcontrol
      email: "CLOUDCONTROL EMAIL"
      password: "CLOUDCONTROL PASSWORD"
      deployment: "APP_NAME/DEP_NAME"
    - provider: heroku
      api_key:
          secure: "My_API_KEY"
      app: MYAPP
```